# Displaying characters typed at mouse location in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, events, keylistener

I have a Java exercise using KeyListeners that I have been stuck on for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The exercise is:

"Write a program to get a character input from the keyboard and display the character where the mouse points."

I did some debugging and it seems like the KeyListener is never registering when a key is pressed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EventProgrammingExercise10 extends JFrame {

    CharPanel chars;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EventProgrammingExercise10 frame = new EventProgrammingExercise10();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public EventProgrammingExercise10() {
        setTitle("EventProgrammingExercise10");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        chars = new CharPanel();

        chars.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                chars.repaint();
            }

        });

        add(chars);
    }

    public void setX(int n) {
        x = n;
    }

    public void setY(int n) {
        y = n;
    }

    class MouseLocListener extends MouseMotionAdapter {

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            setX(e.getX());
            setY(e.getY());
        }

    }

    class CharPanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf('a'), x, y);
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look @Hovercraft and you forget to add the MouseLocListener. Than it works :)

```
chars.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseLocListener());
chars.setFocusable(true);
chars.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Answer (score 4):

A KeyListener will only work if the component that owns it has the ***focus***. You must first make your JPanel focusable, i.e., `setFocusable(true)`, and then request that it have focus, i.e., `requestFocusInWindow()`.

I wouldn't use a MouseListener at all. What I'd do if I had to use a KeyListener, and what I know works, would be:

- Make my JPanel Focusable and have focus
- Give it a BufferedImage that is exactly its size and draw this in its `paintComponent` method.
- Add a KeyListener/KeyAdapter to it
- In the KeyAdapter, `keyPressed` method, Use the MouseInfo class to get a PointerInfo object: `PointerInfo pInfo = MouseInfo.getPointInfo()`
- Use PointerInfo to get the current mouse's location **on screen** via `pInfo.getLocation();`
- Get the drawing JPanel's locationOnScreen.
- Translate the mouse pointer location to one that is relative to that of the component's using simple vector graphics.
- If the point is in bounds of the location, get a Graphics object from the BufferedImage
- Draw the char in the BufferedImage
- Repaint the JPanel

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you should attach lKeyListener not to chars panel but to the frame itself.

This way KeyListener will allways work even if panel losses focus for any reason.

Comment: *"This way KeyListener will allways work even if panel losses focus for any reason"* No, it won't.  The component that steals focus will prevent any other key listeners from been notified.  If you place another component on top the frame that can maintain keyboard focus (such as `JTable`), the frame will never receive keyboard focus, never mind the fact that it isn't focusable (from a keyboard put of few) to start with...